# Django custom app template: How to create directory with app name?

Tags: python, django, templates

The standard Django app template that runs when one invokes `startapp` creates the following files and directories:

```
<app_name>
 |-- migrations
 |    |
 |    +-- __init__.py
 |
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- admin.py
 |-- apps.py
 |-- models.py
 |-- test.py
 |-- views.py
```

I want to create a custom template that will product the following app structure:

```
<app_name>
 |-- migrations
 |    |
 |    +-- __init__.py
 |
 |-- static
 |    |
 |    |-- <app_name>
 |          |
 |          |-- css
 |          |-- img
 |          |-- js 
 |
 |-- templates
 |    |
 |    |-- <app_name>
 |          |
 |          |-- index.html
 |
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- admin.py
 |-- apps.py
 |-- models.py
 |-- test.py
 |-- views.py
```

The trick I am missing is how to setup a template so that certain directories are named using the app name.  This is easy to do for parameters within template files but I am not sure if there's a way to create the  directories under `static` and `template`.

Going to go look at `startapp` source code for clues.  Hoping someone might have an answer for this just the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you accept the answer based on custom management command ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking.  We don't have an answer for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just name the folder `app_name` and it will be named to your app name:

```
app_name/somemodule.py-tpl
```

will be:

```
yourappname/somemodule.py
```

Comment: thank you this actually answers the OP's question and works great (tested with Django 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder called templates in your main directory i.e in the same directory as your app folder. Update the path of `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` variable of your settings.py.
Now django looks for templates in templates directory. You can also add a folder specific to your app inside templates folder and can use `'myapp/template_name'` while rendering.

For static update the variable `STATIC_URL` in your settings.py( add if it doesn't exist). Eg: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`, which looks for a folder named static in current directory which is for specific apps. In a template use `{% load static %}`. Then you can then link to static folder as `href = "{% static 'file_name' %}".`

Comment: I don't think it's answer the question.

Comment: No, this isnt it.  This is about a different kind of template.  This is the template `manage.py startapp <your_app_name_here>` uses when creating the app.  The standard template is located at 

`<path/to/django/source>/django/conf/app_template`.  

You can either change this or create a new template directory elsewhere to pass to `startapp` and it will create the app skeleton according to this template.

You can set it up such that file and directories you want on every app are created when you run `startapp`.